# Large blank space between menu-bar and buffer window

Tags: buffers, menu-bar, tool-bar

There is a large blank space between the top of the buffer and the bottom of the menu-bar in my Emacs 24 on Ubunutu 16.10 that doesn't want to go away.  I've tried Googling but can't really find anything to help, would appreciate some ideas!  Screenshot included:

[image]

Comment: What you mean with `toolbar` is actually the `menu-bar`. I think the large blank space is the real `tool-bar` but maybe your emacs is missing the icons for the tool-bar. You can test whether the large blank space is the tool-bar by switching off Options -> Show/Hide -> Tool-bar.

Comment: Hah.  You are right.  `(tool-bar-mode -1)` is now in my init.el.  Thank you.

Comment: @Tobias: Please consider posting that as an answer, which can then be accepted by OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For marking this question as done I cite my comment below the question as an answer here:

> What you mean with toolbar is actually the menu-bar. I think the large blank space is the real tool-bar but maybe your emacs is missing the icons for the tool-bar. You can test whether the large blank space is the tool-bar by switching off Options -> Show/Hide -> Tool-bar

The original poster added that the assumption from the comment is right and that he switches the tool-bar off by adding `(tool-bar-mode -1)` to his init file.

The remaining question would be why the tool-bar remains empty. This is an error. There should be at least buttons for `find-file`, `menu-find-file-existing`, `dired`, `kill-buffer`, and some more buttons for editing text.

**Update:**
Note, that this is a known problem with emacs24 under [Ubuntu 16.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak).
There already exists [a bug report with a workaround for it at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1623585).